# UIButton as titleview in UINavigationBar weird stretch bug?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to get a `UIButton` as titleview for a `UINavigationBar` (in a `UINavigationController`), but when adding an image to the button it seems to stretch the entire titleview:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong here or is this a bug? Is there a workaround for this? I am running iOS 11 beta 2 so it could just be a beta bug, can't test on iOS10 though.. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

code:

```
let titleButton = UIButton(type: .system)
titleButton.sizeToFit()
titleButton.tintColor = UFOGREENTHEMECOLOR
titleButton.setTitleColor(BLACKTEXTCOLOR, for: .normal)
titleButton.setTitle("John Doe", for: .normal)
titleButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 20)

titleButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "Default Avatar.png"), for: .normal)
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleButton
```

**EDIT:** Tried this on IOS10, same behaviour. Adding `titleButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`
as suggested by [CoderAzreal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8211952/coderazreal) Does seem to fix the image being stretched, but the title is still way off to the right.

Answer (score 2):

Try `titleButton.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit`

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help! I tried it and the image is now fine but the distance is still too big (button title is still in the same place as on the image I posted)

Answer (score 0):

You can add width constraint to your UIButton

```
    [self.search_button addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.search_button
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:nil
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:32]];
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help, I tried this, and unfortunately it's still doing the same thing.. Was a nice suggestion though!